# 25 Cards drawn from a partial deck and placed onto a 5x5 grid

Tags: probability

All the aces, 2’s, 3’s, 4’s, 5’s and 6’s, as well as the jack of diamonds are taken from a
regular deck of 52 playing cards, and then placed face up on a table in a 5 × 5 square
grid configuration randomly.

What is the probability that the ace of hearts, 2 of hearts, 3 of hearts, 4 of hearts,
and 5 of hearts all appear in a single row (it could be in any row and we don’t
care about their ordering within that row).

The two ways I think may be right are either (5/25*4/24*3/23/*2/22*1/21)
=120/6 375 600 or, 4/24*3/23/*2/22*1/21=24/255024

If anyone could explain if either of these methods are correct and why, or why they are both incorrect it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The ace of hearts will appear on one row.

What we require then is the probability that the other four of the remaining 24 cards selected for that row will be the 2,3,4,and 5 of hearts.

$$\frac{1}{\binom{24}{4}} = \dfrac{4!\, 20!}{24!} = \frac{4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}{24\cdot 23\cdot 22\cdot 21}$$

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at it as $25!$ total ways to lay out the cards. Then count how many meet your criteria. Choose the row/column that will have these hearts, then count the number of ways to order those five cards, times the number of ways to lay out the other 20 cards.

$$\frac{5\cdot5!\cdot20!}{25!}$$

This suggests that it can also be viewed as $\frac{5}{\binom{25}{5}}$, which also makes sense. Out of all of the ways to choose the five locations for these five hearts, only five such combinations are actual rows.